# Integral Of $\oint_{|z-i|=1} \frac{z^3}{e^z+i}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to evaluate the following, by finding the points that correspond to the definition
$$\oint_{|z-i|=1} \frac{z^3}{e^z+i}dz$$
What I did is:

1. Find for what values of $z \rightarrow $ $e^z=-i$
   $$z=ln(-i)\rightarrow i(-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k)$$
2. $k=0,1,-1,2,\dots$

So I start checking the numbers:
$k=0 \rightarrow -\frac{\pi}{2}i$ its not in the circle
$k=1 \rightarrow \frac{3}{2\pi}i$ its in the circle? if yes why?
[image: Definition]

What I`m doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $$|i(\frac{3\pi}{2})+1|=1$$

Comment: $\frac{3}{2\pi}i$ Its above 2 sorry..

Comment: "What I`m doing wrong?" Nothing so far. What is the conclusion?

Comment: I dont know what is the answer.

Comment: The integrand is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of the disk $\{z:\lvert z-i\rvert \leqslant 1\}$. What does that tell you about the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or maybe in a simple way (i.e., don't mess with the complex logarithm if you don't *really* have to):

$$-i=e^z=e^x\cos y+ie^x\sin y\iff\begin{cases}\cos y=0\iff y=\frac\pi2+k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\\{}\\e^x\sin\left(\frac\pi2+k\pi\right)=-1\iff x=0\;,\;k\notin 2\Bbb Z\end{cases}$$

The solutions thus are $\;y=\left\{\;...,-\frac\pi2\,,\,\frac{3\pi}2\;,\;\frac{5\pi}2,\ldots\;\right\}\;$

Check now with your drawing what points (only one, by the way) are within that circle...

Comment: But $\frac{3\pi}{2}i$ its not above $2i$?

Comment: @OfirAttia, I did not say $\;\frac{3\pi}2i\;$ is within. You *have* to check which ones of these values are in.

Comment: Still, I dont find the value in the circle. anyway I asked this question because in my answers of my homework there is answer there that $k=1$ and its not correct so I didnt know what right and whats wrong. thanks.